# Why this ts class doesn't run as expected

Tags: jquery, typescript, addeventlistener

In this piece of code, my wish is to :

- get a template ($.get(...)),
- bind a eventListener on the input into the template

Use webpack to transpile the code, and no issue.

The code :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export class TodoForm {
private _input: Element;

constructor(element: JQuery){
    $(function() {
        $.get('./src/Components/todoForm/todoForm.html', (data) => {
            $(element).append(data);

            // Définit le listener sur la zone de saisie
            this._input = document.getElementById('todoContent');
            this._input.addEventListener('keyup', this._setInputListener);
        });
    });
}

private _setInputListener(event: any): void {
    alert('COucou input');
    let _input = $(this._input);
    if(_input.val().length > 0){
        console.log('Active le bouton d\'ajout')
    } else {
        console.log('Désactive le bouton')
    }
}
}
```

When runs... any alert, any console if keyup on the input field...

Don't see why...

Comment: Get an `element` and add `new TodoForm(element);` at the end of your file.

Comment: Also, replace `this._input.addEventListener('keyup', this._setInputListener)` with: `this._input.addEventListener('keyup', ev => this._setInputListener(ev))`

Comment: Well, after update the code, and the keyup is fired on the input field, got a :
 
    TypeError: _this._setInputListener is not a function

as if the eventhandler was created only when user type into the field

Comment: Replace `$(function() {` with `$(() => {`.

Comment: ... okay... replacing function by shorthand will do the job... But, sometimes, have troubles with webpack that consoled "cannot read property call of undefined" and sometimes not... Will continue to code

Answer (score 0):

Your are using `this` on non arrow functions

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export class TodoForm {
  private _input: Element;

  constructor(element: JQuery) {
    $(() => { // You need an arrow function here
      $.get('./src/Components/todoForm/todoForm.html', data => {
        $(element).append(data);

        // Définit le listener sur la zone de saisie
        this._input = document.getElementById('todoContent');
        this._input.addEventListener('keyup', this._setInputListener);
      });
    });
  }

  // This way the function is auto bind to the instance
  private _setInputListener = (event: any): void => {
    alert('COucou input');
    let _input = $(this._input);
    if (_input.val().length > 0) {
      console.log("Active le bouton d'ajout");
    } else {
      console.log('Désactive le bouton');
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Okay... thx... understand narrow function... so, i update the code and want to use jQuery instead of HTMLElement... Following the rules, wrote :

private _jQueryInput: JQuery;
...
this._jQueryInput = $('#todoContent');
...
this._jQueryInput.on('keyup', (event: any): void => this._inputListener(event));

and just refactor the new method... works like a charm...

Thx